# Can a table be created under a database in SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure

Normally I'm familiar with the following hierarchy of items in a SQL Server database:

- Connection

  - Database

    - Schema

      - Table

However, I see some 'system tables' directly under a Database in an Azure SQL Database. Is the schema merely 'suggested' or what are the restrictions on creating tables with/without a schema?

Comment: In Azure SQL, the system tables have different schema, it not `suggested`. We can't create table without schema. If you are server admin or database owner, you could create other schema for the table. The default schema is 'DBO'.

Comment: 1. Schema is mandatory. 2. Not quite sure what you mean by "Connection". Perhaps you mean "Server"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure SQL, the system tables have different schema, it not suggested.

We can't create table without schema. Like @Alex said, schema is mandatory.

Different users may have different schema. We could set the default schema for the user:

```
CREATE USER Wanida FOR LOGIN WanidaBenshoof   
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Marketing;  
GO
```

Or:

```
ALTER USER Mary51 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Purchasing;
GO
```

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#b-changing-the-default-schema-of-a-user-1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-creating-a-database-user-with-a-default-schema